# Encode an encodable struct to Alamofire POST parameters - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, django

I'm trying to connect my front-end iOS app (Swift) to my Django backend.

I try to create an `APIRouter` class that handle any requests. This class need to conform to `URLRequestConvertible`.

I have this struct:

```
struct APIAccountID: Codable {
    
    let username: String
    let password: String
}
```

Which is codable.

I'm trying to pass the data of this struct in an Alamofire POST request.

So I'm trying to get encode the object like this:

```
var parameters: [String: AnyObject]? {
    switch self {
    case .fetchAccessToken(let accountID):
        if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(accountID) {
            return data
        } else {
            print("Error: encoding post data")
            return nil
        }
    default: break
    }
}
```

Which doesn't work because `Any` or `AnyObject` aren't Codable when using Alamofire `URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder` or `JSONParameterEncoder`.

If I use this parameters switch:

```
var parameters: Data? {
        switch self {
        case .fetchAccessToken(let accountID):
            if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(accountID) {
                return data
            } else {
                print("[fetchAccessToken] Error: encoding post data")
            }
        default:
            break
        }
        return nil
    }
```

I get this error when I send the request:

```
{
    "non_field_errors" =     (
        "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str."
    );
}
```

My URLRequestConvertible function:

```
// MARK: - URLRequestConvertible
extension APIRouter: URLRequestConvertible {
    
    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        let url = try baseURL.asURL().appendingPathComponent(path)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.method = method
        if method == .get {
            request = try URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder()
                .encode(parameters, into: request)
        } else if method == .post {
            request = try JSONParameterEncoder().encode(parameters, into: request)
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        }
        return request
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested the code, but clearly the error states that parameters should be of dictionary type, and you are passing string in parameters. You have to create a dictionary, map your model in that dictionary and pass that as parameter

Comment: Just a note: you don't need your explicit `CodingKeys` struct. The keys are by default the same as the property name.

Comment: @George Yeah that is just because the code is auto generated from a script of mine.

Comment: @AmaisSheikh The problem is that I can have multiple types in my struct, and Any or AnyObject aren't codable...

Comment: @PaulBénéteau If you manually send this data, does it work? `Data(#"["username": "Paul", "password": "Bénéteau"]"#.utf8)`. I'm not exactly sure what data it wants, so worth trying that. If that doesn't work, try remove the `"` from the keys. If we know the correct input, we can then solve how to get that input from your struct.

Comment: @George It works if I send this: ["email": accountID.username, "password": accountID.password]
but I want my code to handle any struct and with any type (int, string, double,...)

Comment: @PaulBénéteau As a `String` converted to `Data`, right?

Comment: @George I've updated my question. I just added much more details so you can understand.

Comment: Why are you even using `parameters`?  If your object conforms to `Encodable` then you can just pass it directly to `URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder` or `JSONParameterEncoder`. That's the point.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah that is what I was think about... 
I'm learning with this guide: https://www.raywenderlich.com/11668143-alamofire-tutorial-for-ios-advanced-usage
I don't know how to pass it directly to `URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder` or `JSONParameterEncoder` because `asURLRequest()` is a protocol method...
He is using an enum for his Router so it adapts to all request. But I can't use 'AnyObject'...

Comment: Surely all you need to specify is `var parameters: Encodable?`

Comment: @Paulw11, I get this error: `Protocol 'Encodable' as a type cannot conform to the protocol itself` for `URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder` and `JSONParameterEncoder`.

Comment: Your right, I had more of a dig into the docs. `Parameters` needs to be a `Dictionary<String:Any>`.  There is no simple way to pass an arbitrary struct that conform to `Encodable` to Alamofire.  You could add an `asParameters` computed property to your structs that return the required dictionary, but that looks like the kind of malarkey that these encoding functions should avoid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237012/discussion-between-paulw11-and-paul-beneteau).

Comment: @PaulBénéteau FYI, my PR has been accepted so you should be able to use the original AnyEncodable package rather than my fork.

Answer (score 0):

The AlamoFire `URLFormEncodedParameterEncoder` and the `JSONParameterEncoder` can accept anything that conforms to `Encodable`, so you don't need to use `JSONEncoder` first; They take care of that.

Your root problem is what should be the type of `parameters` given that you will have a different parameter type, depending on the API call.

You can't say

```
var parameters: APIAccountID
```

because that won't work for the case where parameters is a `updatePortfolio` or whatever.

And you can't simply say `var parameters: Encodable?` because you need a concrete type.

You need to use *type erasure*.  This is a technique that is used in Swift to allow otherwise unrelated types to be used as a parameter.  There are various approaches, but a common one is "boxing" where the actual type is stored as a property and when you refer to the type erased type you redirect that reference or function call in to the boxed or wrapped type.

So, in this case what you need is an `AnyEncodable` - A type erased implementation of `Encodable`.  Luckily, just such a thing is available from the FlightSchool repos - https://github.com/Flight-School/AnyCodable

Once you add that package to your project you can modify `parameters` to

```
var parameters: AnyEncodable? {
    switch self {
        case .fetchAccessToken(let accountID):
            return AnyEncodable(accountID)
        case .updatePortfolio(let portfolio):
            return AnyEncodable(portfolio)
    }
}
```

Now, our `parameters` var has a fixed type - `AnyEncodable?`, which conforms to `Encodable` so everyone is happy.  The implementation requires that you instantiate an instance of `AnyEncodable` with your actual `Encodable`